# Package Web app with MSBuild on Windows Server 2012 RC

Tags: msbuild, webdeploy, iis-8

I'm using a Windows Server 2012 RC with IIS 8 (on Windows Azure, the new VMs).

I've got TeamCity installed as my build server. I migrated from a current installation where everything worked fine.

The only thing that doesn't work is running MSBuild with the Package target against an ASP.NET MVC 3 application.

The last section of the MSBuild log, just before it has to actually create the package looks like this:

```
[MyProject\MyProject.MvcClient\MyProject.MvcClient\MyProject.MvcClient.csproj] PipelinePreDeployCopyAllFilesToOneFolder
[21:46:16][PipelinePreDeployCopyAllFilesToOneFolder] GetPublishingLocalizedString
[21:46:16][GetPublishingLocalizedString] Publish Pipeline Deploy phase Pre-Deploy CopyAllFilesToOneFolder Stage
[21:46:16][MyProject\MyProject.MvcClient\MyProject.MvcClient\MyProject.MvcClient.csproj] Package
[21:46:16][Package] GetPublishingLocalizedString
[21:46:16][GetPublishingLocalizedString] Invoking Web Deploy to generate the package with the following settings:
[21:46:16][Package] GetPublishingLocalizedString
[21:46:16][GetPublishingLocalizedString] $(LocalIisVersion) is 7
[21:46:16][Package] GetPublishingLocalizedString
[21:46:16][GetPublishingLocalizedString] $(DestinationIisVersion) is 7
[21:46:16][Package] GetPublishingLocalizedString
[21:46:16][GetPublishingLocalizedString] $(UseIis) is True
[21:46:16][Package] GetPublishingLocalizedString
[21:46:16][GetPublishingLocalizedString] $(IisUrl) is http://myproject.web
[21:46:16][Package] GetPublishingLocalizedString
[21:46:16][GetPublishingLocalizedString] $(IncludeIisSettings) is true
[21:46:16][Package] GetPublishingLocalizedString
[21:46:16][GetPublishingLocalizedString] $(_DeploymentUseIis) is True
[21:46:16][Package] GetPublishingLocalizedString
[21:46:16][GetPublishingLocalizedString] $(DestinationUseIis) is True
[21:46:16][Package] GetPublishingLocalizedString
[21:46:16][GetPublishingLocalizedString] $(IisUrl_SiteID) is 2
[21:46:16][Package] GetPublishingLocalizedString
[21:46:16][GetPublishingLocalizedString] $(IisUrl_SiteFriendlyName) is myproject.web
[21:46:16][Package] GetPublishingLocalizedString
[21:46:16][GetPublishingLocalizedString] $(IisUrl_SiteRelativePath) is /
[21:46:16][Package] GetPublishingLocalizedString
[21:46:16][GetPublishingLocalizedString] $(IisServer_IisAppPoolName) is myproject.web
[21:46:16][Package] GetPublishingLocalizedString
[21:46:16][GetPublishingLocalizedString] $(_Destination_IisServer_IisAppPoolName) is myproject.web
[21:46:16][Package] MakeDir
[21:46:16][MakeDir] Creating directory "F:\Workspace\DeployPackages\2012-07-11_09-45-53\".
[21:46:16][Package] CallTarget
[21:46:16][CallTarget] GenerateMsdeployManifestFiles
[21:46:16][GenerateMsdeployManifestFiles] GetPublishingLocalizedString
[21:46:16][GetPublishingLocalizedString] Generate source manifest file for Web Deploy package/publish ...
[21:46:16][GenerateMsdeployManifestFiles] CallTarget
[21:46:16][CallTarget] CollectDatabasesToPublish
[21:46:16][CollectDatabasesToPublish] MakeDir
[21:46:16][MakeDir] Creating directory "obj\Release\Database".
[21:46:16][CallTarget] PackageUsingManifest
[21:46:16][PackageUsingManifest] GetPublishingLocalizedString
[21:46:16][GetPublishingLocalizedString] Packaging into F:\Workspace\DeployPackages\2012-07-11_09-45-53\MyProject.msbuild.zip.
[21:46:16][PackageUsingManifest] VSMSDeploy
[21:46:16][VSMSDeploy] Starting Web deployment task from source:manifest(F:\Workspace\DeployPackages\2012-07-11_09-45-53\MyProject.msbuild.SourceManifest.xml) to Destination:package(F:\Workspace\DeployPackages\2012-07-11_09-45-53\MyProject.msbuild.zip).
[21:46:16][VSMSDeploy] C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(3009, 5): Web deployment task failed. (There was an error reading IIS configuration schema from 'C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\config\schema\'.)
[21:46:16][VSMSDeploy] Package failed.
[21:46:16][MyProject\MyProject.MvcClient\MyProject.MvcClient\MyProject.MvcClient.csproj] Project MyProject\MyProject.MvcClient\MyProject.MvcClient\MyProject.MvcClient.csproj failed.
[21:46:16][MyProject\MyProject.msbuild.teamcity] Project MyProject\MyProject.msbuild.teamcity failed.
[21:46:16]Process exited with code 1
```

And the actual error message being this:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(3009, 5): Web deployment task failed. (There was an error reading IIS configuration schema from 'C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\config\schema\'.)
```

First, I tried running the build agent as Administrator, since I thought this might be security related. That didn't help.

Then I tried to install Web Deploy 3.0 on the server. No luck either.

Last thing I can do, but really don't want to do -- is to remove the IIS settings from the project file.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you install the latest Azure SDK (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=254269)? This scenario is not supported in VS 2010 SP1 without the Web Publish Update that is included in the latest Azure SDK.

Comment: This is not Visual Studio, or developing for Azure. It is just TeamCity running on an Azure virtual machine.